# Pedals turn but front sprocket does not

Tags: gears, pedals

My Mountain Bike ,about ten years old,Three (3) sprockets in front.
It backpedals (whizzz) But when I go to pedal there is no engagement - Pedals turn but sprockets don't move..But sprockets move when backpedaling.

> edit<- I searched Batman's & the other person mentioned for this "Duplicate question" but found none similar.
>    It's Shimano parts , the pedal arm is white aluminum, the *chaingears*, is that the word for sprocket ? The Chaingear/sprocket where the chain rides on is Black Aluminum.
>     When I look behind the assembly,Down at the crank axle,  and while turning crank by using pedal, A round circular part is turning with the pedal , But it is perfectly round and factory made like that ,Looks like a part of chaingear, It's also Black Aluminum, Maybe there's a catch or pin that's broke ?
>   While I grasp the pedal and crank forward , both pedals turn as supposed to , But the chaingear/Big circular saw piece remains idle, It does not move , 
>   But it moves when backpedaling, As does the gears on the rear tire..
>
> > > edit edit>> 
> > >         I proceeded to cross a peculiarly arranged intersection, I deemed the coast clear , 5 feet from safety my pedals gave out , I could pedal easily and freely but no movement on my front chaingear and as a result - No torque available to propel my rear gear into saving my life.
> > >        A car whizzed around the corner and straight at me at the same time my 21 speed Mountain Bike with GTX tires Shit thine bed

Comment: Please take a look at the above link and let us know if it describes the problem. If it doesn't, then we'll need a bit more information to go by, and perhaps a photograph, if you're able...

Comment: that's still a bit vague, but it's beginning to smell like a Shimano "front freewheel" system. Does it say "Octalink" anywhere on the crank? If so, the crank is a bizarre contraption that's probably hosed, and needs replacing. I'd take it to your LBS and ask them to take a look; if they concur then I'd ask them to put a nice normal crankset on it.

Comment: There's an old tag on it , hard to read , But it says , "Inex Rowher" Or that's a part of it..What I'm seeing from looking behind it appears to be the crank arm turning

Comment: Yep, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_freewheel .  There are even some pictures.  The article says "Non-proprietary front freewheels can currently be found on bikes used for bike trials riding."  Otherwise the bike would probably have to date from before 1990 or so.

Comment: Thanks Dan - But No , alas it's not what cheesy gizmo I have on mine.

Comment: ..Or more like "Inde..Prowheel" IS-38

Comment: Please post a picture of your crankset. That will help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Despite your edits, there is not enough information to tell whether this is different from the question listed as the duplicate. It's unlikely that this will be reopened without a picture of the crankset and a clearer description of how the behavior is different from that of the duplicate question.

Comment: I saw the duplicate , I was directed to it.THAT'S IT alright, same set-up ,swag.